# How to send a message to everyone execpt the sender socket.io

Tags: reactjs, express, websocket, socket.io

I know that to do such a thing we have to write socket.broadcast.emit('chat message', 'hello guys')
but in my case when I do this, nothing happens, I still receive the message in my browser.
As I understood socket.broadcast works this way if I send a message from my browser I must not see it but I do see.

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('a user connected');
  socket.broadcast.emit("hello", "world");


  socket.on('chat message', (msg) => {
    console.log('message: ' + msg);
    socket.emit("chat message", msg)
    socket.broadcast.emit("chat message", msg) <=== doesn't work
  });

  socket.on('typing', (data) => {
    io.emit('typing', data)
  })

  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('user disconnected');
  });
});
```

React

```
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import {io} from "socket.io-client";
import {Button, ChatField, ChatFieldArea, Input, Wrapper} from "./styled/appstyled";


function App() {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("")
  const [messageList, setMessageList] = useState([])
  const [typing, setTyping] = useState(false)


  const ENDPOINT = "ws://localhost:4444";
  const socket = io(ENDPOINT, {transports: ['websocket']});

  let typingTimer;

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("chat message", (data) => {
      setMessageList(p => [...p, data])
    })

    socket.on("typing", (data) => {
      setTyping(data)
    })

    return ()=>{
      socket.disconnect();
    }

  }, [])

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    if (message.length > 0) {
      socket.emit('chat message', message);
      socket.emit('typing', false)
      setTyping(false)
      setMessage("")
    }
  }

  return (
      <h1>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <ChatFieldArea>
            <ChatField>
              {messageList.map((el, i) => {
                return (
                    <span key={i}>{el}</span>
                )
              })}
            </ChatField>
            <Wrapper>
              <Input onChange={(e) => {
                if (e.target.value.length > 0) {
                  setMessage(e.target.value)
                }
              }} value={message}
                     onKeyDown={(e) => {
                       if (e.key !== 'Enter') {
                         setTyping(true)
                         socket.emit('typing', true)
                         clearTimeout(typingTimer)
                       }
                     }}
                     onKeyUp={() => {
                       clearTimeout(typingTimer)
                       typingTimer = setTimeout(() => {
                         socket.emit('typing', false)
                         setTyping(false)
                       }, 1000);

                     }}/>
              <Button type={"submit"}>Click</Button>
            </Wrapper>
            {typing ? "typing" : 'not typing'}

          </ChatFieldArea>
        </form>
      </h1>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are using both  `socket.emit` and `socket.broadcast.emit`. If you only want to send messages to users other than senders then remove `socket.emit` call

`socket.emit` - sends message to sender

`socket.broadcast.emit` - sends message to everyone except sender

So you should update your code to:

```
socket.on('chat message', (msg) => {
    console.log('message: ' + msg);
   // socket.emit("chat message", msg)  REMOVE THIS
    socket.broadcast.emit("chat message", msg) // WILL send to everyone except sender
});
```

Comment: it doesn't work, I tried both way, but socket.broadcast.emit("chat message", msg) doesn't work, it sends text to all users and to me as well